# Django-Rest-Framework 'str' object has no attribute 'id'

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I am creating a call in DRF to POST to the site. I am a bit confused why I get this error. I do not understand why this expects it to be a str. I know there are similiar posts but they still elude be to the solution.

**Error**

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'id'
[03/Apr/2018 10:55:12] "POST /api/user/UserProfile/1/ HTTP/1.1" 500 83982
```

**serializer.py** looks like and if I remove instance.id i get the same error but just for the next line.

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from api.models import UserProfile
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    # id = serializers.UUIDField()
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return UserProfile.objects.create(**validated_data)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.id = validated_data.get('profile_id', str(instance.id))
        instance.user_id = validated_data.get('user_id', instance.user_id)
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

**View**

```
@csrf_exempt
def user_profile_list(request, user_id):
    try:
        userid = user_id
    except userid.DoesNotExist:
        return HttpResponse(status=404)

    if request.method == 'GET':
        uprofile = UserProfile.objects.all().values()
        list2 = list(uprofile)
        return JsonResponse(list2, safe=False)

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        data = JSONParser().parse(request)
        serializer = UserProfileSerializer(userid, data=data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return JsonResponse(serializer.data, status=201)
        return JsonResponse(serializer.errors, status=400)
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^api/user/UserProfile/(?P<user_id>[0-9]+)/$', userprofile.user_profile_list),
```

Comment: The error message is clear, debug your code and see why `instance` is getting a `str`.

Comment: django noob....no clue how to do that

Comment: Please read [the debugger docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html) then, it's a good tool to know!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You passed to serializer `userid` instead of user object. To update object with serializer, you should pass instance as first argument. Change view to this:

```
elif request.method == 'POST':
    data = JSONParser().parse(request)
    user = User.objects.get(id=userid)
    serializer = UserProfileSerializer(user, data=data)
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

**AttributeError**

The issue lies in the line `serializer = UserProfileSerializer(userid, data=data)` where you're passing `userid` to the serializer instead of a user *or* user profile instance, I say *or* because the logic is not very clear to me (using a UserProfileSerializer but updating User instance?).

**Improvements**

What you are trying to accomplish with your code can be done in an easier way:

1. Use a [ModelSerializer](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#modelserializer) instead of a Serializer
2. Use a [ModelViewSet](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#modelviewset) instead of a function-based view (`user_profile_list`)

A generic version using ModelSerializer and ModelViewSet would be something along the following lines:

serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from api.models import UserProfile


class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        # preferably listing the fields to avoid any code breaking
        # if you add fields to the model later on
        fields = '__all__'
```

views.py

```
from rest_framework import viewsets

from api.serializers import UserProfileSerializer
from api.models import UserProfile


class UserProfileViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = UserProfile.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserProfileSerializer
```

I highly recommend going through [DRF's official tutorial](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/quickstart/), it will save you alot of development time if you understand which parts of your app are already implemented in DRF and can be directly used with little code.